# LINQ SUM with EF Core "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Int32'"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to sum a column in a LINQ query with Entity Framework Core using a MySQL connector.

My Query:

```
_context.Cities
            .Where(c => c.Player == name)
            .Where(c => c.Timestamp == max)
            .Sum(c => c.Score);
```

I receive this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal'
>   to type 'System.Int32'.

I've read through dozens on SO posts and cannot figure out what is wrong. I have also tried an explicit cast with `.Sum(c => (int)c.Score)` and still receive the same exception.

How can I sum this property within the query?

**Edit**: `Score` is not nullable. `Score` is also an int in the model as well as the database.

**Edit2:** `.Sum(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Score))` works! Though I feel like that should not be necessary?

Comment: The error indicates the value is not an integer.  It may be null so try .Sum(c => (int?)c.Score

Comment: Are you sure that problem is there? What is Timestamp and max' type?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. It only occurs when trying to sum. Timestamp and player work exactly as expected.

Comment: Quick questions: 1-What's the type of 'Score' column in the table (DB)? 2- What's the type of 'Score' property in the Cities class? 3- What's the type of variable that the value of Sum is being assigned to it? (if this statement has a left hand side)

Comment: @FeryalBadili I added an edit with some of that info. I'm trying to assign it to an int. I have also tried to assign it to a decimal, int?, and just var. The issue seems to be in the query itself.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell  Is it possible for you to try this same query with a previous version of EF, maybe using LinqPad?

Comment: Did you happen to change score column type from decimal to int in MySQL, but didn't update the corresponding EF model?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and your suggesting of using `Convert.ToInt32` also worked for me - thanks! This looks like it's a bug with EF Core and `.Sum()`.